# How to prevent python program working with filesystem on mac create .DS_STORE files and break its execution

Tags: python, macos

I have code like this:

```
for directory in os.listdir(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        # Do stuff
```

I know there are only directories in path. Program creates `.DS_STORE` in `directory` and quits with `Not a directory` error. The program was written for Linux and Windows and I don't want to change her. How could I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that it's your program creating `.DS_Store` files.  They are usually created by Finder, and a program written for Linux and Windows is unlikely to create these macOS-specific files.

So the program can't handle unexpected file/dir hierarchy.  I would argue that it's a problem with its design.  You can clean up your dirs somehow before launching the program itself, but the natural way to fix the issue is to write more robust code handling common use cases.

Comment: I checked directory from terminal and made sure, that there are no temporary files. But when I start the program, it is appearing.

Comment: @Intolighter: so you think that the program written to work on **Linux and Windows**, creates **macOS-specific files** to trip itself up and crash?  It doesn't make *any* sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to see if the current directory is actually a directory.

```
for directory in os.listdir(path):
    current_dir = os.path.join(path, directory) #creates the path to the current directory
    if os.path.isdir(current_dir): #verify that the path is actually a directory
        for file in os.listdir(current_dir):
            current_file = os.path.join(current_dir, file) #create path to file inside directory
            if os.path.isfile(current_file): #verify that the path is actually a file
                # Do stuff
```